# if radio button is selected show text insite text field

Tags: jquery

I have to use jquery 1.3.2
I have here very simple task to check if button is selected and display a custom text inside certain textfield accordingly. I know that the problem is somewhere in the condition. Inside of condition is simple code to show custom text inside textfield with focus and blur functions

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('input#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---0').is(":checked")) {
    $('input.default').val('xxx');
    $('.default').each(function () {
      var defaultVal = ('xxx');
      $(this).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == defaultVal) {
          $(this).removeClass('active').val('');
        }
      })
        .blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal);
        }
      })
        .blur().addClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

Can you please help me debug why does not this code work with the condition? Thank you. Full code with html is here http://jsfiddle.net/NKcFs/

EDIT: On my page, there are more rediobuttons. I need to show text only if this certain button is selected. If visitor selects another button, the text should dissapear.

Comment: you JSFiddle contains something really different from this example..

Comment: @ZoltanToth sorry it is fixed now

Comment: Minimal working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e7dPc/

Comment: @RichardTowers that is very easy approach, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code only runs when the page loads. If the radio button is selected that that point, then the code actually shows the text in the textbox. To make the code react to changes in the checkbox you should use the `change` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---0').change(function(){
    if ($('input#edit-quote-option-flatrate-3---0').is(":checked")) {
      $('input.default').val('xxx');
      $('.default').each(function () {
        var defaultVal = ('xxx');
        $(this).focus(function () {
          if ($(this).val() == defaultVal) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').val('');
          }
        })
          .blur(function () {
          if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).addClass('active').val(defaultVal);
          }
        })
        .blur().addClass('active');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh, that was crucial for real time updating. However that brought me to other, issue. I updated my question as well - the text remains visible even user changes mind and chooses different button instead. How to overcome this?

Comment: @user1031742: You should have an `else` in the `if` statement where you remove the text, and unbind the `focus` and `blur` events.